# Long Text Area field behaving as case sensitive while searching a keyword

Tags: long-text-area, case-sensitive

I have a Long Text Area(500) field `Description__c` on `Account` object.
When i'm trying to search a keyword in this field value, it seems it's behaving as Case sensitive to find that keyword.

For e.g.

```java
Description__c = 'Batch/lot number requested, not available at the time of call. Caller refused follow-up.'

String searchText = 'batch'
 
String searchtext1 = 'Batch'
```

When i'm trying to find `searchText1` in `Description__c`, it's working fine.
But when i'm trying to find `searchText`, it's returning false and not working.

I've already tried below ways to fix it.

```
1.  if(Account.Description__c.toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())){}
2.  if(Account.Description__c.toLowerCase().containsIgnoreCase(searchText.toLowerCase())){}
3.  if(Account.Description__c.containsIgnoreCase(searchText)){}
```

Please help me to fix this case sensitive behaviour of this long text area custom field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why would you expect the results to work as case-insensitive. It's not something related to `Long Text Area field`. It's just because field returns a String & this is how apex treats Strings.

The string class already has methods to do both case-sensitive/insensitive checks.

**contains(substring)**

> Returns true if and only if the String that called the method contains the specified sequence of characters in substring.

**containsIgnoreCase(substring)**

> Returns true if the current String contains the specified sequence of
> characters without regard to case; otherwise, returns false.

```
String description = 'Batch/lot number requested, not available at the time of call. Caller refused follow-up.',
    searchString = 'batch',
    searchString1 = 'Batch';

System.assert(description.contains(searchString1), 'Either the string was not part of actual string or the case didnt matched'); //passes
System.assert(description.containsIgnoreCase(searchString), 'The string was not part of actual string'); //passes
```

You just have to pick the correct one based on your requirement.